# Unable to Subtract Dates SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to get a Date time difference with this query:

```
SELECT BASESCORE, 
       Max(CONVERT(DATETIME, '')) - Min(CONVERT(DATETIME, '')) AS datediff 
FROM   log 
GROUP  BY BASESCORE 
ORDER  BY BASESCORE
```

it works fine but the out it gives my is wrong:

```
   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
   1900-01-01 00:00:00.000
                    ......
```

How can i get the right out put from the above query!

Comment: that query makes no sense.

Comment: can u pls explain why you have tagged java?

Comment: You are converting empty strings to `datetime`? What are you trying to achieve? What are your column names for dates?

Comment: I am totally new to SQL I need some help

Comment: If you add some sample data (maybe in SQL Fiddle), we can give you a better answer.

Comment: did you tried `DATEDIFF`??

Comment: yes i tried it me an error all the time

Comment: What **datatype** is that column holding the dates in your SQL Server table??

Comment: I assume you want the difference between the earliest and latest in each 'basescore', correct?

Comment: yes it is the problem is that i want to get the difference grouped by my basescores

Comment: if you named a column datetime, you might want to consider renaming it (or use [datetime] every time you use it). and as marc_s said: what is the datatype of your datetime column. it will matter if it's a string or a datetime (the datatype)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see from your post edit last time, value from field datetime like '20/Mar/2013:03:17:44'. Format from value of datetime can't convert by a simple way.

Try this query:

```
SELECT BASESCORE, 
       [DATEDIFF]= Datediff(second, Min(CONVERT(DATETIME, 
                                        LEFT(Rtrim(Ltrim(DATETIME)), 
                                        11) + ' ' 
                                        + RIGHT(Rtrim(Ltrim(DATETIME) 
                                        ), 8))), Max 
                               ( 
                               CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(Rtrim(Ltrim(DATETIME)), 11 
                                                 ) + ' ' 
                                                 + RIGHT(Rtrim(Ltrim(DATETIME)), 
                                                 8)))) 
FROM   temptabel 
GROUP  BY BASESCORE 
ORDER  BY BASESCORE
```

Output:

```
Basescore    datediff
1            1
2            0
3            0
```

You can see at [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0792c/2)

Comment: Wow you really helped me out dear +1

Comment: @Gidil, I use trim only for anticipation if there is a value that contains spaces

Comment: @user2496503: Thx, but if you show your schema table, maybe you can get a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

As @Nithesh said, try to use `DATEDIFF` -

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE(
       [datetime] DATETIME
     , basescore INT
)

INSERT INTO @temp
VALUES
     ('20130320 03:17:43', 1),
     ('20130320 03:17:43', 2),
     ('20130320 04:17:43', 1),
     ('20130320 03:20:43', 2)

SELECT
       basescore
     , [datediff] = CONVERT(
                         VARCHAR(10), 
                         DATEADD(ms, 
                         DATEDIFF([second], MIN([datetime]), MAX([datetime])) * 1000, 
                    0), 114)
FROM @temp
GROUP BY basescore
ORDER BY basescore
```

Output -

```
basescore   datediff
----------- ----------
1           01:00:00:0
2           00:03:00:0
```

Comment: This is a much better answer since it is complete!

Comment: Down-voter please tell what's wrong in my and @Nithesh answers?

Comment: @Devart he thinks that all so peoples are there for to feed the exact query and we get paid for that.. :D crazy...

Comment: @Nithesh we're just helping people. You shouldn't pay attention to someone who think differently. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score 3):

Using the sample data you posted (and adapting it slightly), here is my attempt to solve the problem:

```
SELECT BASESCORE, 
       Datediff(dd, MINDATE, MAXDATE) 
FROM   (SELECT BASESCORE, 
               Cast(Max(DATETIME) AS DATETIME) MaxDate, 
               Cast(Min(DATETIME) AS DATETIME) MinDate 
        FROM   table1 
        GROUP  BY BASESCORE)T
```

You can take a look at the full working version on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/32c9e/4).

Let me know if there was something I misunderstood ;-)

Comment: its working fine for SQLFiddle but now I have accepted your answer because its working correctly! but later on I will give you the feedback

Answer (score 2):

Earlier you showed you dateformat, you deleted the format again, but i had time to copy it.
It seems to me that this is your desired query and result:

```
declare @t table(datetime char(20), basescore int)
insert @t values('20/Mar/2013:03:17:43', 1),('20/Mar/2013:03:17:43', 2)
                ('20/Mar/2013:04:17:43', 1),('20/Mar/2013:03:20:43', 2)

SELECT basescore,  MAX(convertdate) - MIN(convertdate) AS datediff
-- when selecting from your own table remove '@t' from next line
FROM @t log
cross apply(select cast(stuff([datetime], 12, 1, ' ') as datetime) convertdate) a
group by basescore order by basescore
```

Result:

```
basescore   datediff
1   1900-01-01 01:00:00.000
2   1900-01-01 00:03:00.000
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DATEDIFF()`.

Syntax : `DATEDIFF(datepart,startdate,enddate)`

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Comment: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: -1? Why negative mark.. please explain. datediff is not an option for date subtraction?? crazy